# apache derby: specifying an ID for a column "GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY"

Tags: sql, primary-key, derby, auto-increment, javadb

The following sql statements for apache derby works fine:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby://uri';

create schema TEST02;
set schema TEST02 ;

create table T
    (
    id INT not null primary key GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    name varchar(50) not null unique
    );  


insert into T(name) values ('NAME02');
insert into T(name) values ('NAME03');
select * from T;
drop table T ;
drop schema TEST02 RESTRICT;


disconnect;
```

output:

```
ij> insert into T(name) values ('NAME02');
1 row inserted/updated/deleted
ij> insert into T(name) values ('NAME03');
1 row inserted/updated/deleted
ij> select * from T;
ID         |NAME                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------
1          |NAME02                                            
2          |NAME03
```

but when I 'know' the id of some records, and I set the id in my INSERT statement:

```
## here I set the id column

ij> insert into T(id,name) values (1,'NAME01');
1 row inserted/updated/deleted

ij> insert into T(name) values ('NAME02');
ERROR 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL130515100041380' defined on 'T'.
ij> insert into T(name) values ('NAME03');
1 row inserted/updated/deleted
ij> select * from T;
ID         |NAME                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------
1          |NAME01                                            
2          |NAME03                                            

2 rows selected
```

how can I fix this, how can I have an auto_increment column where I can, sometimes, set the primary key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for ALTER TABLE ... RESTART WITH. Here's the docs:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html#rrefsqlj81859__rrefsqlj37860